# What type of mental illness does Nina suffer from?

Tags: character, black-swan

What type of mental illness does Nina suffer from? It looks like she has schizophrenia. Her mother also appears to be unwell or just extremely overbearing.

Comment: I thought she is just extremely tensed and obsessed with her goal to the point of sickness. No illness per se.

Answer (score 5):

I would surmise that Nina is experiencing a [psychotic break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychotic_break) as a result of extreme pressure.  Her mother shows signs of having [narcissistic personality disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder) or some other personality disorder.

Answer (score 4):

[Wiki says..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Swan_%28film%29)

> The production requires a ballerina to play the innocent and fragile
>   White Swan, for which the committed dancer Nina (Portman) is a perfect
>   fit, as well as the dark and sensual Black Swan, which are qualities
>   embodied by the new arrival Lily (Kunis). Nina is overwhelmed by a
>   feeling of immense pressure when she finds herself competing for the
>   part, causing her to lose her tenuous grip on reality and descend into
>   a living nightmare.

So just like @aman_abhishk said, it was pressure.